# Tomcat, Spring boot, Maven - error running tomcat port out of range -1. Как настроить?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-ee, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

Пишу web приложение c Spring boot, собираю war с помощью maven и далее нужно задеплоить на tomcat. ide - intellij idea.
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.antoncharov</groupId>
    <artifactId>chat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>chat.VkChatApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vk.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

настройки конфигурации запуска
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске проект собирается и видимо при попытке деплоя выдает error running tomcat port out of range -1
Tomcat установил и запустил. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно задать любой порт в server.xml в папке conf томката

```
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Правда я так и не понял, что это и зачем.